# Always disable epsv when using git-ftp from a certain directory

Tags: git, ubuntu, ftp, git-ftp

I have one server where I push data to that requires me to add `--disable-epsv` at the end of the git-ftp command. This is of course an exception, so I forget it often. Is there a way to set it in the config file so it always does that for me?

Supposing there is no way to do that, using linux, can we write an alias that will let us overwrite the command say "git-ftp" to write "git-ftp %s --disable-epsv" automatically?

Answer (score 3):

That option has been introduced in [commit 3ea099d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ea099d48b15f69889f4efe71599c9dfde6bb26a) by Sasha Khapyorsky for Git 1.4.3-rc1 in Sept. 2006, with the following comment:

> If `http.noEPSV` config variable is defined and true, or if
>   `GIT_CURL_FTP_NO_EPSV` environment variable is defined, disable using
>   of EPSV ftp command (`PASV` will be used instead).
>   This is helpful with some "poor" ftp servers which does not support EPSV mode.

So you have two options: a config or an environment variable.
The config [http.noEPSV](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-httpnoEPSV)  still mentions today (2017):

> A boolean which disables using of EPSV ftp command by `curl`.
>   This can helpful with some "poor" ftp servers which don’t support EPSV mode.
>   Can be overridden by the `GIT_CURL_FTP_NO_EPSV` environment variable.
>   Default is false (curl will use `EPSV`).
>
> from a certain directory

If you can limit that to one repo, then a local config is enough:

```
cd /path/to/where/espv/must/be/disabled
git config http.noEPSV true
```

Comment: Unfortunately, git-ftp ignores that.